# who to make jquery function work with all input

Tags: jquery, css

is it possible to make this work with all inputs i have on my checkout page? - So i dont need to make new one, like i do now ?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkout-firstnamea').blur(function(){
         if (this.value == "") { 
            $(this).removeClass("asd");
            $(this).addClass('asd-red');
        }
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkout-lastnamea').blur(function(){
         if (this.value == "") { 
            $(this).removeClass("asd");
            $(this).addClass('asd-red');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: use `$('input:text')` this will be used for all input type text

Comment: IDs need to be unique for an HTML page. You can do this by assigning a common CSS class for all such inputs, and then change your selector to `$(".your_class_name").blur( ... );`. You can also use HTML data attributes to do the same.

Comment: Then should use `$('input')` OR you need to use **Class selector**. And a your script in a common JS page which will be included all page.

Comment: side note: you were not obliged to have 2 `$(document).ready` here, multiple actions can be performed inside a single one, of course

Answer (score 1):

Since the content of the handlers is the same, all you need is a selector to select all of the target elements.  For example, this would select exactly those *two* inputs:

```
$('#checkout-firstnamea, #checkout-lastnamea')
```

Or this would select all text inputs:

```
$('input[type="text"]')
```

Or this would select all inputs on the page:

```
$('input')
```

Or inputs and selects:

```
$('input, select')
```

Or all inputs and selects within a specified container element:

```
$('#someContainer input, #someContainer select')
```

etc.

Basically, craft your selector to identify the entirety of what you want to identify.  The same handler would be applied to all matching elements.  There's a *wide* variety of selectors you can use in the jQuery documentation, which can be combined in any way you need.

Comment: Nice! - what if i have a<p> that i want to change the color of, but i not want it to change all <p> only the one with <p>First name</p>, when the input field for first name is empty

Comment: @MarkJ, what you're asking it really depends on the markup.

Comment: <div><p>Fornavn</p><input type="text" id="checkout-firstnamea" class="asd"></div> @Ionut

Comment: @MarkJ: If that target can be found relative to the handler element, then you can use DOM traversal methods to find it.  As an example: $(this).closest('div').find('p.someClass')

Comment: @MarkJ, in that specific case you can use `$(this).prev().css('color', '#f00');` inside your code. Here is a taste of it https://jsfiddle.net/bdbagkL7/2/

Comment: @Ionut That is nice, that's really nice, is it possible to add some text too? .. like with js innerHTML .. is thier a function in jquery?

Comment: @MarkJ, yes there are. Depends on what you are trying to achieve. Where do you want to add the text? Alternative to `innerHTML` in jQuery is `html()` - http://api.jquery.com/html/ and for `innerText` is `text()` http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: @Ionut .. you know .. like 

First name .. and if the field is empty 

First name - this req.

Comment: @Ionut Cool my friend! - I think i can modify your script, or .. you have told me how to make my dreams come true :) - Thx a lot! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the ids separated by `,` in the same place and use the `blur` only once:

```
$('#checkout-firstnamea, #checkout-lastnamea').blur(function() {
  if (this.value == "") {
    $(this).removeClass("asd");
    $(this).addClass('asd-red');
  }
});
```

`$('input')` should do the trick also, but this will select all the inputs without taking in the consideration the type of it:

```
$('input').blur(function() {
  if (this.value == "") {
    $(this).removeClass("asd");
    $(this).addClass('asd-red');
  }
});
```

But if you want to target specific input types you can use(in this case we target for type `text`, but it can be either `checkbox, email, tel` etc):

```
$('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {
  if (this.value == "") {
    $(this).removeClass("asd");
    $(this).addClass('asd-red');
  }
});
```

This will work for inputs of type `text`. Another way(and I think this is a better approach) would be to have same `class` on the elements you want to target.

Comment: shouldnt :text be specified ? input will also select checkbox and radio button

Comment: @guradio, I was just on the way to update the answer. See now please.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple in jquery. You can select all of the inputs as:

```
 $('input') // This will select all of the inputs on your page.
```

If you want to select only `input type="text"`, you can do the following:

```
 $('input[type="text"]')
```

If you want to select only `input type="checkbox"`, you can do the following:

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]')
```

If you want to loop your selection, you can do the following:

```
  $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
       $(this) // here it is your current input element which is a textbox
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use input selector instead of id :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').blur(function({
       if (this.value == "") { 
        $(this).removeClass("asd");
        $(this).addClass('asd-red');
    }
    }));
});
```

If it's on a specific form you can use :

```
$('#yourformid input[type="text"]')
```

instead of :

```
$('input[type="text"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily achieved by some common class.

To do it add common class to needed elements:

like below suppose `checkout_fields` is your common class so do it like:

```
<input type="text" name="checkout-firstnamea" class="checkout_fields" id="checkout-firstnamea">

<input type="text" name="checkout-lastnamea" class="checkout_fields" id="checkout-lastnamea">

$(document).ready(function(){

     $(document).on("blur",".checkout_fields",function(){

           if ($(this).val() == "") { 

               $(this).removeClass("asd");
               $(this).addClass('asd-red');
          }

    });

});
```